# Can we create a swipeable tabs in IONIC 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

Theres a way to create swipeable tabs on Ionic 3 in library 3.

But a lot has changed in Ionic 4, There are swipeable tabs but without animation.

It doesn’t work the same way anymore, so I wanted to know if its possible to do the same effect with Ionic 4.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so someone showed me this alternative, it's a little hacky but I think it will do for now.

Might also help others so I will post link

https://gist.github.com/JCKodel/4c5ee68a38c0648c5833d7c9e85bdd35